# Is there any way to put subcategories in a Joomla menu?

Tags: articles, menu, front-end, subcategories

I've been trying to change the way my website works. Currently, I have a menu that displays categories, but now I want to also display subcategories in it. I know that I can display articles of that category, but can't seem to find an answer anywhere about subcategories.

This is for Joomla 3.9.2. Most of the answers or posts that I have found are for Joomla 1.2, which was back in 2011 (at least most of the posts are from that time). ex: https://developer.joomla.org/joomlacode-archive/issue-29278.html https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=673844

Comment: These looks _slightly_ more recent: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/8940/12352 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/17451905/2943403  If a feature is not readily available from the core, the next stop to make is to the [JED](https://extensions.joomla.org/)

Comment: Are you trying to display a List of the sub categories or a Blog of items in those sub categories? If it is a List does a Menu type of Articles->List All Categories  work for your needs or if it is a Blog then the Articles->Blog and then the Subcategory Levels field settings under the Category/Categories Tabs might help.

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks a lot ! i'll be looking into it !

Comment: @Irata tried it :/ didn't wortk